# 3D Touch and SpriteKit

Tags: swift, 3dtouch

Has anyone played around with 3D touch and spritekit?.

I have been watching some tutorials about 3d touch and it seems fairly simple for the most part. However all tutorials are about regular apps using multiple view controllers (using storyboard IDs, previewControllers etc)

Is it possible to integrate 3D touch with SpriteKit which usually only has 1 ViewController.

My plan would be to

1) HomeScreen shortcuts which would load different scenes (shop scene, level1, level 2 etc)

2) Peek and Pop, maybe for menus. Can you even use peek and pop for things such as SKNodes?

Thanks for any tips or suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can integrate 3D Touch and SpriteKit.

Using the default SpriteKit game project template (Swift), set your `GameScene` to be a `UIViewControllerPreviewingDelegate` and implement the protocol's methods, like this:

```
public class GameScene: SKScene, UIViewControllerPreviewingDelegate {
  public func previewingContext(previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing, viewControllerForLocation location: CGPoint) -> UIViewController? {  
    return UIViewController()
  }

  //Pop
  public func previewingContext(previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing, commitViewController viewControllerToCommit: UIViewController) {
    return
  }
}
```

In GameViewController.swift's `viewDidLoad`, add the following:

```
if let scene = GameScene(fileNamed:"GameScene") {
  if self.traitCollection.forceTouchCapability == .Available {
    registerForPreviewingWithDelegate(scene, sourceView: scene.view!)
  }
}
```

In the delegate method, I am returning an empty view controller. You can create a class-level variable and instantiate this VC with appropriate `peek`-type views. Again, a very simple example. If you want to add 3D Touch from an AppIcon interaction, you will need to modify Info.plist and add capabilities from the AppDelegate. [There is a good video on this topic](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NO9E5KxixOw). Good luck!

Comment: Your the man. I'll try this when I got some time after the holidays. I'll post some feedback soon. Thanks a lot.

Comment: How should I identify which object was pressed with this code?